# How can I center an image on a textView who is attached to a NSTextAttachment type?

Tags: swift, nstextattachment

I have a textView (programmatically) and I inserted an image appended to a NSTextAttachment and want it to be aligned to the center of the text view... but I haven't found any solutions yet...I was wondering if that task is possible to be done via code only...

```
    let image = ResizeImage(image: UIImage(named: "logo")!, targetSize: size)

    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()

    image1Attachment.image = image

    let image1Attachments = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
```

My best approach to the solution on trying to achieve this was this code :

```
    let image = ResizeImage(image: UIImage(named: "telepaint1")!, 
    targetSize: size)

//let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
//let imageStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    let imageStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //imageStyle.alignment = .center
    imageStyle.alignment = .center
    //textAttachment.image = image
    textAttachment.image = image
    let imageText = NSAttributedString(attachment: 
    textAttachment).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    //attempt to center image...
    let attributedStringToAppend: NSMutableAttributedString = 
    NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: 
    NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n"))

    //attributedStringToAppend.addAttributes(attr, range: range)

    let combination2: NSMutableAttributedString = 
    NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: 
    NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n"))


    combination2.append(lineBreak)
    // combination2.addAttribute(attr, range: NSRange(location: 0, 
    length: length))

    combination2.append(imageText)
    //this text will display the "Walktrough" text on image 

    combination2.append(attributedText)

    tv.attributedText = combination2
```

Comment: You should make use of the paragraph style you created. The code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349587/show-text-cursor-on-drag-and-drop-in-uitextview) does just that.

Comment: But ai already tried it that way...still xcode gives me errors...

Comment: The code in your question makes no attempt to center the image and it looks nothing like the code I linked. Update your question with your attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Answer(worked for me!):

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))

    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)


    //Here is an attempt to resize image and center it...



    let image = ResizeImage(image: UIImage(named: "logo")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), targetSize: size)


    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()


    let imageStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()


    imageStyle.alignment = .center


    textAttachment.image = image


    let imageText = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString

    let length2 = imageText.length

    imageText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: imageStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length2))
```